# Create multi user JAVA program, with Derby, assigning Server dynamically

Tags: java, network-programming, derby, multi-user

I´d like to create a Java application to distribute to users in a LAN, where the first who runs the app becomes the server, all the others must access to Derby DB such that they are clients. In my scenario I couldn't leave Derby running as a service, but must be started at first run of the app. Some hints?

Comment: That seems really hard. How would the other users figure out which user had become the server? And if that user exited your application, and thus was no longer the server, what would the other users do?

Comment: Correct. It's exactly my trouble. I need to share a quite small data source, among few users. It could also be a text file, a CSV or whatever. I also need to structure some forms for inserting and querying data. The only constraint is that I couldn't leave running any server, like a DB or a web server locally

Comment: Hmmm... Perhaps Derby isn't the right tool for that problem.

Comment: any solution is welcome...